# Emulate middle mouse click by pressing the two buttons at the same time

Tags: windows-xp, mouse, synaptics-touchpad

I upgraded the driver of my Synaptics Touchpad under XP and I can no longer press the left and right buttons simultaneously to simulate a middle click. How can I turn this back on?

Comment: Minesweeper supports the middle button ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This forum post](http://forum.notebookreview.com/hp-compaq/205207-those-synaptics-touchstyk-trackpoint-any-way-enable-middle-button-scrolling.html) has a solution. I've also verified it works under Windows 7 Professional 64-bit on an HP ProBook 6550b.

1. Run the registry editor (`regedit`)
2. Go to key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Synaptics\SynTP\Defaults\`
3. Create a new key as a `DWORD` and name it as `HasBothButtonFeature` and set the value to `1`.
4. Log off and Log on again.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: This answer works for previous versions of Synaptics driver. In newer version, I can't find a way to configure the two buttons together.** In this case, only tricks like using GlovePIE or maybe AutoHotkey will help with it. It's a pity that they removed this functionality.

---

In mouse options (from control panel), you should have extra tabs for "Buttons" for the touchpad, installed by Synaptics drivers.

There you can choose what the two button pressed at same time do. (At least it is like that on mine, it could have changed in a newer version)

[image: screenshot]

*I apologize for the French version, I couldn't find an English screenshot, so I did it myself.*

Comment: *Going to reinstall my previous drivers, now*

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather roundabout way of doing it, but there is a program called GlovePIE, a Programmable Input Emulator, that uses a simple scripting language to make an input function as any other output as desired. You can get the program here: http://glovepie.org/